# Google Cloud - Stack recommendation for Tomcat/PostgreSQL/HTTPS/SFTP site?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

This is my first attempt at looking into cloud hosting and I'm feeling like a complete idiot. I have always had my own dedicated server with which I would would remote in and install/manage everything myself. So this cloud thing is completely new for me. I just can't seem to grasp basic things... like how I would get Tomcat and PostgreSQL installed in a way that they could talk to each other or get my domain and SSL cert on there, etc.

If I could just get a feel for where I should start, then I could probably calculate my costs and jump into the free trial where hopefully things will click for me.

Here are my basic, high-level requirements...

- My web app running in Tomcat over HTTPS
- Let's say approximately 1,000 page views per day
- PostgreSQL supporting my web app.
- Let's say approximately 10GB database storage
- Throughout the day, a fairly steady stream of inbound SFTP data (~ 100MB per day)

The processing load on the app server side should be fairly light. The heaving lifting will be on the DB side sorting through and processing lots of data.

I'm having trouble figuring out which options I would install and calculating costs. If someone could help me get started by saying something like "You would start with a std-xyz-med server, install ABC located here at http://blahblah, then install XYZ located at http://XYZ.... etc.. etc.  You can expect to pay somewhere around $100-$200 per month"....

Thoughts?

I would be eternally grateful. It seems like they should have some free sales support channel to ask someone at Google about this, but I don't see it.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to give you some tips where to start looking.
I will be referring to some products, here are the [links](https://cloud.google.com/products/)

1. If you want to stick to your old ways, you can always spin up an instance on Compute Engine and set it up the same way you did before, these are just regular virtual machines. For some use cases this is completely valid.
2. You can split different components of your stack to different products:

   - For example, if your app is fine with postgresql, you can spin up a fully managed service in Cloud SQL, which might make it easier to manage backup or have several apps access the same db.
   - Alternatively, have a look at the different DB offerings to see if any of them matches your needed workload better. Perhaps have a look at BigQuery?
   - If you want to turn your app into a microservice, which is then easier to autoscale and is more fault tolerant, have a look at App Engine. That way you don't need to manage a virtual machine. The docs here will lead you through some easy to follow examples on how to set up SSL.
   - For the services to talk to each other, refer to docs of the individual components. It's usually very simple.
   - With pricing, try https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/
     Things like BigQuery have different pricing models - you don't pay for server uptime, but for amounts of data stored & processed with your queries.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, much appreciated. You have given me some new starting points and buzzwords to research.
BTW - I was familiar with price calculator. But because I didn't know what options I needed/wanted, I had no idea what to put in to most of those fields. haha